# .NET MAUI Keyboard click propagation on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, browser, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Anyone has experienced the problem in Blazor Hybrid MAUI that in iOS (iPad) when you type on the keyboard, click events gets "through" to the elements behind it. So for instance I have a textarea behind the native keyboard that pops up and whenever I type the keyboard then closes and focuses on the element which was behind the keyboard.

Anyone experienced this and/or has solved this issue?